# Radgridview visual issue

Tags: c#, radgridview

I have problem displaying the columns correctly,

some columns have some gap in between

I wanted to attach a picture but I need 10 reputation points to post image

See picture link below!!

Here is my code:

```
private void UpdateProducts()
    {            
        MyPharmacyDataContext db = new MyPharmacyDataContext();            
        int tabid = Convert.ToInt32(radRibbonBar1.SelectedCommandTab.Name);
        var list = from g in db.OutOfStocks
                   where g.ListID == tabid
                   select new { g.ID, g.Product.CName, g.Required, g.Product.Price, g.Product.Disscount, g.Product.BuyPrice, g.TotalBuy, Stock = g.Product.Available + "," + g.Product.AvailableMid + "," + g.Product.AvailableSmall,g.Product.Supplier.Title };
        if (list.Count() > 0)
        {
            radGridView1.SummaryRowsBottom.Clear();
            radGridView1.Columns.Clear();

            radGridView1.Visible = true;
            radGridView1.TableElement.TableHeaderHeight = 60;
            GridViewTextBoxColumn num = new GridViewTextBoxColumn();
            num.MaxWidth = 50;
            num.Name = "num";
            num.HeaderText = "م";
            num.DataType = typeof(int);
            radGridView1.Columns.Add(num);

            radGridView1.DataSource = list;

            radGridView1.Columns[1].IsVisible = false;                

            radGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 350;
            radGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "اسم المنتج";
            radGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Name";
            radGridView1.Columns[2].TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            radGridView1.Columns[3].MaxWidth = 60;
            radGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "عدد";
            radGridView1.Columns[3].TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            radGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Q";

            radGridView1.Columns[4].MaxWidth = 90;
            radGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "السعر";
            radGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Price";
            radGridView1.Columns[4].TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            radGridView1.Columns[4].FormatString = "{0:G29}";

            radGridView1.Columns[5].MaxWidth = 80;
            radGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "الخصم";
            radGridView1.Columns[5].TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            radGridView1.Columns[5].FormatString = "{0:G29}";

            radGridView1.Columns[6].MaxWidth = 100;
            radGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "سعر\nالشراء";
            radGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "BuyPice";
            radGridView1.Columns[6].TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            radGridView1.Columns[6].FormatString = "{0:G29}";

            radGridView1.Columns[7].MaxWidth = 100;
            radGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = "اجمالي\nالشراء";
            radGridView1.Columns[7].Name = "TotalBuyPice";
            radGridView1.Columns[7].TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            radGridView1.Columns[7].FormatString = "{0:G29}";

            radGridView1.Columns[8].MaxWidth = 80;
            radGridView1.Columns[8].MinWidth = 80;
            radGridView1.Columns[8].Name = "Stock";
            radGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = "الرصيد";
            radGridView1.Columns[8].TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            radGridView1.Columns[9].MaxWidth = 100;
            radGridView1.Columns[9].MinWidth = 100;
            radGridView1.Columns[9].Name = "Supplier";
            radGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = "افضل\nمورد";
            radGridView1.Columns[9].TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;                

            GridViewCheckBoxColumn checkbox = new GridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            checkbox.MaxWidth = 30;
            checkbox.HeaderText = "";
            checkbox.DataType = typeof(bool);
            checkbox.Name = "Ordered";
            radGridView1.Columns.Add(checkbox);

            var allpro = from g in db.OutOfStocks
                         where g.ListID == tabid
                         select g;
            foreach (OutOfStock p in allpro)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in radGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if ((int)row.Cells[1].Value == p.ID)
                    {
                        if (p.Ordered == 'y')
                            row.Cells["Ordered"].Value = true;
                        else
                            row.Cells["Ordered"].Value = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            GridViewSummaryItem total = new GridViewSummaryItem("Name", "الاجمالي", GridAggregateFunction.Avg);
            GridViewSummaryItem price = new GridViewSummaryItem();
            price.Name = "Price";
            price.AggregateExpression = "(Sum(Q*Price))";
            price.FormatString = "{0:G29}";
            // GridViewSummaryItem price = new GridViewSummaryItem("Price", "{0}", GridAggregateFunction.Sum);
            GridViewSummaryItem buypice = new GridViewSummaryItem("TotalBuyPice", "{0:G29}", GridAggregateFunction.Sum);
            GridViewSummaryRowItem summaryRowItem = new GridViewSummaryRowItem(new GridViewSummaryItem[] { total, price, buypice });

            radGridView1.SummaryRowsBottom.Add(summaryRowItem);
            radGridView1.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            radGridView1.Visible = false;
        }

        if (radGridView1.Rows.Count() > 0)
            radGridView1.ChildRows.Last().IsCurrent = true;
    }
```

Here is the pic
[https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/10893575_742987025776952_423788280_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoidCJ9&oh=c69f42a8f47d6529f2b9d89ab2782711&oe=54A71C8A&**gda**=1420210517_66e1b08ccf9c00fd3dcff31e1854b3cc](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/10893575_742987025776952_423788280_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoidCJ9&oh=c69f42a8f47d6529f2b9d89ab2782711&oe=54A71C8A&__gda__=1420210517_66e1b08ccf9c00fd3dcff31e1854b3cc)